Inalla, Archmage Ritualist and Mistbind Clique interaction?
If I play a Mistbind Clique, I have to sacrifice it unless I exile another Faerie I control (and the Faerie will then return when Mistbind Clique leaves the battlefield).
Inalla, Archmage Ritualist has "Whenever another nontoken Wizard enters the battlefield under your control, if Inalla, Archmage Ritualist is in the command zone or on the battlefield, you may pay 1. If you do, create a token that's a copy of that Wizard. The token gains haste. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step."  Mistbind Clique is a Faerie Wizard.
If I have sufficient mana available, and Inalla is in the Command Zone, would the timing of triggers work so I can make a token copy of the Mistbind Clique and have the token champion the original each time the original Mistbind Clique enters the battlefield?

Yes, you can do this.
Both Mistbind and Inalla have triggered abilities that trigger at the same time. So the next time a player would get priority, you can put them both on the stack in the order of your choosing. Importantly, neither triggered ability targets, so you are not making any decisions about them when you put them on the stack.
So you put Mistbind on the stack first, and then Inalla. Inalla resolves first, so you create a token copy of Mistbind. This causes another triggered ability to trigger and go on the stack. Mistbind token's triggered ability resolves, so you choose a Faerie to champion, choosing the original Mistbind. Then, the original Mistbind's ability finally resolves, and you choose to not sacrifice anything, which would cause the Mistbind to be sacrificed, but nothing happens because it's already gone.

603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.


603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, the abilities are placed on the stack in a two-part process. First, each player, in APNAP order, puts each triggered ability they control with a trigger condition that isn’t another ability triggering on the stack in any order they choose.

